# bootstrap multi item carousel moving at one item at once click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Bootstrap multi item carousel moving at one item, 
I copied code from this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/at606jpe/), now i am trying to implement this in my local environment(localhost) with same effect but it is coming different ? can you please help

**Added Link of CSS and JS**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
.carousel-inner .active.left  { left: -33%;             }
.carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%;              }
.carousel-inner .next         { left: 33%               }
.carousel-inner .prev         { left: -33%              }
.carousel-control.left        { background-image: none; }
.carousel-control.right       { background-image: none; }
.carousel-inner .item         { background: white;      }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 10000
    })

    $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      if (next.next().length>0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
      else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JSFiddle that well, but I've tried to copy and paste the fiddle in my own starters template and it works fine. I guess you didn't include jquery or something like that. My code should work, except you have to check if you have the css, jquery, javascript an glyphicons included. So my advice is to download a bootstrap starting folder (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.6/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist.zip) and paste the code in a index.html file..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Bootstrap starters template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">


<style>
    .carousel-inner .active.left  { left: -33%;             }
    .carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%;              }
    .carousel-inner .next         { left: 33%               }
    .carousel-inner .prev         { left: -33%              }
    .carousel-control.left        { background-image: none; }
    .carousel-control.right       { background-image: none; }
    .carousel-inner .item         { background: white;      }
</style>



</head>

<body>


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>



<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>

    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 10000
    });

    $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        if (next.next().length>0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: IT WORKING BUT 3 ITEMS IS SHOW I NEED 4 ITEM I TRIED  COL-MD-4 TO COL-MD-3 BUT IS NOT DISPLAYING 4 ITEM AT TIME

Comment: Thats not what you asked for and also not showing in the jsfiddle.. Can't help you with that because its a javascript problem